# Ignoring nil parameters in array select

Tags: ruby

### Example

The user has made a search and has specified an age but not a number of children, i.e. wants to find people with any number of children, including zero.

```rb
array = []
obj1 = {:name => "Steve", :age => 32, :children => 2}
obj2 = {:name => "Dave", :age => 37, :children => 4}
obj3 = {:name => "Barry", :age => 40, :children => 0}
array << obj1
array << obj2
array << obj3
puts array

## replicating incoming search parameters
params = {}
params[:age] = 35
params[:children] = nil

matching_params = array.select{|person| person[:age] > params[:age] && person[:children] > params[:children]}
```

If I run this code, I will get an error that it can't compare a number with `nil`.

### Workaround

If I change the children part to `&& person[:children] > (params[:children] || -1)` then this will show all people over 35. For this situation, it does what's required.

### Problem

Imagine, however, a world where it's possible to have a negative number of children...I would have to change -1 to minus infinity. Is there some way to just exclude any search criteria which have nil values?

Comment: You could use `person[:children].to_i`. `nil.to_i` is 0 and it will have no effect on integers.

Comment: That would still exclude people with this imaginary negative number of children (I know, I should have made a better example)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Explicitly filter in `nil`s.

```rb
array = [
  {:name => "Steve", :age => 32, :children => 2},
  {:name => "Dave", :age => 37, :children => 4},
  {:name => "Barry", :age => 40, :children => 0}
]

params = {age: 35, children: nil}

matching_params =
  array.select do |person|
    (params[:age].nil? || person[:age] > params[:age]) &&
    (params[:children].nil? || person[:children] > params[:children])
  end
```

Comment: I see you will soon be rolling five nines.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I prefer to call it _six figures_ :)

Comment: I was alluding to [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AI7cJWNMorE) at 0:32.

Answer (score 0):

**Code**

```
def select_by_age_and_children(arr, params)
  arr.select do |p|
    p[:age]      > (params[:age] || -1) &&
    p[:children] > (params[:children] || -1)
  end
end
```

**Examples**

```
array = [
  {:name => "Steve", :age => 32, :children => 2},
  {:name => "Dave", :age => 37, :children => 4},
  {:name => "Barry", :age => 40, :children => 0}
]
```

```
params = { age: 35, children: 1 }
select_by_age_and_children(array, params)
  #=> [{:name=>"Dave", :age=>37, :children=>4}]
```

```
params = { age: 35, children: nil }
select_by_age_and_children(array, params)
  #=> [{:name=>"Dave", :age=>37, :children=>4},
  #    {:name=>"Barry", :age=>40, :children=>0}]
```

```
params = { age: 0, children: 1 }
select_by_age_and_children(array, params)
  #=> [{:name=>"Steve", :age=>32, :children=>2},
  #    {:name=>"Dave", :age=>37, :children=>4}]
```

```
params = { age: nil, children: nil }
select_by_age_and_children(array, params)
  #=> [{:name=>"Steve", :age=>32, :children=>2},
  #    {:name=>"Dave", :age=>37, :children=>4},
  #    {:name=>"Barry", :age=>40, :children=>0}]
```

**Alternative design**

Consider writing the method as follows:

```
def select_by_age_and_children(arr, params)
  arr.select { p[:age] >= params[:age] && p[:children] >= params[:children] }
end
```

and then instead of calling it with, say:

```
params = { age: 35, children: nil }
```

call it with:

```
params = { age: 36, children: 0 }
```

As well as simplifying the code this avoids the need for the reader to understand what is meant by a `nil` value in `params`.